# Why image resize when open website on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Why image resize when open website on mobile?

https://jsfiddle.net/udwsdpv8/

```
<img src="http://mobiletest.me/themes/sky/phone_thumbs/ipad_mini.png">
<img src="http://mobiletest.me/themes/sky/phone_thumbs/ipad_mini.png">
<img src="http://mobiletest.me/themes/sky/phone_thumbs/ipad_mini.png">
<img src="http://mobiletest.me/themes/sky/phone_thumbs/ipad_mini.png">
<img src="http://mobiletest.me/themes/sky/phone_thumbs/ipad_mini.png">
```

My website on mobile shows like this:

[image]

But I want it like this on mobile (real image size):

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: website image link not working

Comment: Where not working ?

Comment: this link not open http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/iz/160912053032.jpg

Comment: I was update image link success ^_^

Comment: Images is as same as in every resolution. What is issue then?

Comment: i want to show mysite like this https://i.imgsafe.org/6415f9515f.png (real image image size )in every screen resolution.

Comment: Yes they are behaving like this. I just  checked your fiddle and images are looking the same.

Comment: yes , on fiddle and image that i'm looking for are same but when open on mobile image still resize

Comment: Are you using the [`viewport` meta tag](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-multi-screen-site/responsive?hl=en#add-a-viewport)?

Answer (score 0):

add media query like this way

```
@media(max-width:600px){
  img{width:100%;}
}
```

Comment: sorry to say but images are already behaving as op wants them.